# Does OpenSceneGraph use the core profile?

Tags: opengl, openscenegraph

> ..as well as extending our support for desktop/workstation OpenGL with
>   support for OpenGL 3.x and OpenGL 4.x and associated cutting edge
>   extensions

I was wondering if it is possible to use the core profile, or if they rely on the compatibility profile?

> an application written using the core profile of OpenGL will run
>   faster than that same application but modified to use the
>   compatibility profile, even if it only uses features that are
>   available in core profile OpenGL. *superbible 6th*

Comment: "would be faster" is a terrible oversimplification, so if you are asking merely about performance, then uh, I'd -1 it.

Comment: *"even if an application is written in the compatibility profile with no usage of deprecated functions, the same application would be faster if it would use the core profile"* - I highly doubt that and would like to see that proved somehow (or at least stated within some meaningful context). The truth of this statement (or the conditions under which it might be true) might be a much better question than the internals of OSG. But good to see that the newest *Redbook* has finally catched up and dropped all the deprecation confusion.

Comment: In general, it is safe to assume that if an OpenGL program/library does not *explicitly* state in its documentation that it supports the core profile, then it does not.

Comment: I was wrong, the new superbible 6th stated that the core profile would be faster, I added the quote.

Comment: AFAIK OSG is just a scene graph .You can use OGL version whatever you want with slight modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems OSG does not support the Core Profile, see [this](http://forum.openscenegraph.org/viewtopic.php?p=53748#53748)